# laravel model mutators not accessing the defined field

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-models

I am trying to define a model mutator

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Custom_fields extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'custom_fields';

    public function setContentAttribute($value){
        return unserialize($value);
    }
}
```

and on test controller, tried

```php
Custom_fields::all()[0]->content;
```

Unfortunately, it is not working; the value is still not an array (serialize)

I want to access the field `content` and unserialize the value of the field so I can get an array automatically on retrieve, but it's not working.

Comment: may be it would be `setContentAttribute($value)`

Comment: @sta the field name is '_content' did tried, unfortunately same results

Comment: If Eloquent allows defining `content` and a `_content`, both will have the same mutators functions `setContent` https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L432

Comment: @sta tried to change _content to content and tried setContentAttribute($value) but unfortunately same, results if I do Custom_fields::all()[0]->content

Comment: If content is a field which needs to store serialized array data which when retrieved should again be automatically unserialized to array - maybe attribute casting is what you need. protected `$casts = ['_content' => 'array'];` on `Custom_fields` model class. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to "get an array automatically on retrieve" with a method called `setContentAttribute`. You are confusing [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) and [mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator). As the method name implies, the mutator is called when you **set** the `content` attribute.

To create an accessor that is called when you **get** the `content` attribute:

```php
public function getContentAttribute($value)
{
    return unserialize($value);
}
```

Likely if this data is to be stored in a serialized form you want your mutator to look like this:

```php
public function setContentAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes["content"] = serialize($value);
}
```

But really, you should not be using these serialization functions at all. Laravel can [natively convert](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) objects to JSON for storage in a database. Simply define the property in your model's `$casts` property and data will be converted automatically when getting or setting the property.

```php
protected $casts = [
    "content" => "array",
];
```

Comment: how to access the cast field, tried Custom_fields::all()[0]->_content but it returns null

Comment: Obviously it won't work with data that wasn't JSON encoded going into the database.